# Searching an element for a number then inputting number as data

Tags: javascript, counting

**In all honesty, I have no idea where to start. *I'm new to JavaScript*** and have been looking at different things.

One of them is to calculate a sequence of numbers with and come back with a whole value for all calculations, e.g.

[image: Sequence of numbers]

I have to divide each of the sequences by 3, round the number down and subtract 2. Then take each value, add them up and come up with a total.

> What I have so far...

HTML:

```
<p id="groupNumbers"> 
56833 117651 56733 89472 91010 119618 85667 141042 106401 121495 50136 83755
122558 149188 110381 132060 145791 141381 136467 104712 133530 65297 52640 
59637 78410 107791 96909 136738 109794 66831 58426 97955 90496 119294 83101 
80466 114370 67631 106482 73996 50367 113976 68998 109714 96308 89350 143077 
102052 93325 86870 94449 119448 53472 140668 64989 112056 88880 131335 94943 
88061 122883  129059 55345 82362 60500 147652 83147 87106 97384 136883 62198 
130290 129715 93082 72179 2109 70604 94894 98139 97056 86236 144191 108008 
79225 93551 103116 130702 87599 143630 104476 108922 134209 85636 81591 
127980 90425 126133 118135 93722

</p>
<h1>Total: <span id="result"> #### </span> </h1>
```

JavaScript:

```
var numberInput = document.getElementById("groupNumbers");
let divide = numberInput / 3,
  roundDown = Math.round(divide) - 2,
  result = console.log(roundDown);

function calculateNumbers() {
  var num = "";
  var matches = num.match(/(\d+)/);

  if (matches) {
    document.getElementById('groupNumbers').innerHTML = console.log(matches);
  }

  console.log(num);
}

calculateNumbers();
```

What I need is to scan each number segment separately, apply that to a data field and then add the numbers together after the sum for each has been created. A little complicated...

Expected outputs for numbers (requested) [1st 6 number sequences for example]:

```
56833 = 18942
18942 = 6312
56733 = 18909
89472 = 29822
91010 = 30335
119618 = 39871

total for changed HTML span value = 144,191
```

I've gotten a little lost in what I need to do next, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the numbers `p` as `html` code in your question body.

Comment: add few numbers and expected output

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "apply that to a data field"?

Comment: You say you're a little lost in what you need to do next, but what does the code you've written do now? Have you solved any of the problem at all? I think you should be starting at step 1: "how do I turn a string of numbers `'120 651 8967'` into an array of numbers."

Comment: `document.getElementById('groupNumbers').innerHTML = console.log(matches)` assigns `void` to `innerHTML` of `#groupNumbers`. This is logical error. Pls fix.

Comment: You'll probably get help in the future if you can make a simple semi-working example in jsfiddle, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/e3fabydh/)

Comment: Or by adding a code snippet on StackOverflow, which is preferred over using third-party websites. @TKoL

Comment: @Daan fair enough. I've used this website for a long time and never actually figured out how to make a runnable html+javascript snippet on here until I took the time to mess around with it just now. Will be using that in the future, thanks

Comment: I re-edited it. to fit an example.

Comment: I've been looking online for the best method to store each number value to add them all up at the end, that's what I mean by data field, because I don't know where I would store them properly. - An array would make the best sense, but pushing each individual sum is a struggle for me,.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1zt0p3wy/

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou @TKol for pointing me in the right direction with the array.

Answer below:

```
var a =  "115919,56833,117651,56733,89472,91010,119618,85667,141042,106401,121495,50136,83755,122558,149188,110381,132060,145791,141381,136467,104712,133530,65297,52640,59637,78410,107791,96909,136738,109794,66831,58426,97955,90496,119294,83101,80466,114370,67631,106482,73996,50367,113976,68998,109714,96308,89350,143077,102052,93325,86870,94449,119448,53472,140668,64989,112056,88880,131335,94943,88061,122883,129059,55345,82362,60500,147652,83147,87106,97384,136883,62198,130290,129715,93082,72179,72109,70604,94894,98139,97056,86236,144191,108008,79225,93551,103116,130702,87599,143630,104476,108922,134209,85636,81591,127980,90425,126133,118135,93722";


var b = a.split(',').map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
});

//Forms variable into an array.

    for (var i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
        (b[i] /= 3);
    }

//Divides array items by 3.

var x = 0;
    var len = b.length
        while(x < len){ 
        b[x] = b[x].toFixed(0); 
        x++
    }

//Rounds divided array down to whole numbers

function sum(input){
    if (toString.call(input) !== "[object Array]")
    return false;
        var total =  0;
            for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++)
    {                  
    if(isNaN(input[i])){
    continue;
    }
    total += Number(input[i]);
    }
        return total;
}

console.log(b);
console.log(sum(b));
```

Console returns:

```
JavaScript1.js:35 (100) ["38640", "18944", "39217", "18911", "29824", "30337", "39873", "28556", "47014", "35467", "40498", "16712", "27918", "40853", "49729", "36794", "44020", "48597", "47127", "45489", "34904", "44510", "21766", "17547", "19879", "26137", "35930", "32303", "45579", "36598", "22277", "19475", "32652", "30165", "39765", "27700", "26822", "38123", "22544", "35494", "24665", "16789", "37992", "22999", "36571", "32103", "29783", "47692", "34017", "31108", "28957", "31483", "39816", "17824", "46889", "21663", "37352", "29627", "43778", "31648", "29354", "40961", "43020", "18448", "27454", "20167", "49217", "27716", "29035", "32461", "45628", "20733", "43430", "43238", "31027", "24060", "24036", "23535", "31631", "32713", "32352", "28745", "48064", "36003", "26408", "31184", "34372", "43567", "29200", "47877", "34825", "36307", "44736", "28545", "27197", "42660", "30142", "42044", "39378", "31241"]0: "38640"1: "18944"2: "39217"3: "18911"4: "29824"5: "30337"6: "39873"7: "28556"8: "47014"9: "35467"10: "40498"11: "16712"12: "27918"13: "40853"14: "49729"15: "36794"16: "44020"17: "48597"18: "47127"19: "45489"20: "34904"21: "44510"22: "21766"23: "17547"24: "19879"25: "26137"26: "35930"27: "32303"28: "45579"29: "36598"30: "22277"31: "19475"32: "32652"33: "30165"34: "39765"35: "27700"36: "26822"37: "38123"38: "22544"39: "35494"40: "24665"41: "16789"42: "37992"43: "22999"44: "36571"45: "32103"46: "29783"47: "47692"48: "34017"49: "31108"50: "28957"51: "31483"52: "39816"53: "17824"54: "46889"55: "21663"56: "37352"57: "29627"58: "43778"59: "31648"60: "29354"61: "40961"62: "43020"63: "18448"64: "27454"65: "20167"66: "49217"67: "27716"68: "29035"69: "32461"70: "45628"71: "20733"72: "43430"73: "43238"74: "31027"75: "24060"76: "24036"77: "23535"78: "31631"79: "32713"80: "32352"81: "28745"82: "48064"83: "36003"84: "26408"85: "31184"86: "34372"87: "43567"88: "29200"89: "47877"90: "34825"91: "36307"92: "44736"93: "28545"94: "27197"95: "42660"96: "30142"97: "42044"98: "39378"99: "31241"length: 100__proto__: Array(0)
JavaScript1.js:36 3330157
```

Tying it into the HTML is another story, but I'll look more into it. For now, the JavaScript side will do.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8ty6fp0u/7/ -- I forgot to subtract the 2 so added a loop method for that too. (Final edit is int he jsFiddle link.